# How to know IndexPath of next seleted row at didDeselectRow of previous selected row?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

I want to know row of people current selected row at didDeselectRowAt of previous selected row. I tried to use "tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows" but it return nil. I think because table view deselected previous selected row when call didDeselectRowAt fund. I wonder how can I access row table view store to call didSelectRowAt of row which user selected after didDeselectRowAt of previous selected row.   
 Could anyone help me please. I use swift 3.

 Thank you so much.

Comment: What you tried also provide code here.

Answer (score 1):

You need to take two var properties

```
var currentIndexSelected  : Int
var previousIndexSelected : Int
```

when user clicked on `didSelect` assign

```
currentIndexSelected  = indexPath.row
```

and when user clicked on `didDeselect` assign

```
previousIndexSelected  = currentIndexSelected
```